# Format javascript date to match rails format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, date

I get a date back from rails that looks like: 
"2010-10-29T00:00:00+00:00"

And I'd like to convert a javascript date created by 'new Date()' to that format. Is there an easy way?

Comment: Can you use the Datejs library, http://www.datejs.com/ ?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for ISO 8601 format.

I've always been fond of the [Date.js Library](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) for any date manipulation/formatting in JS.

you can use the the toISOString() method to get this format

Answer (score 0):

using dateformat you can format date as you want

TRY these

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format

http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to parse an [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string. A quick google search returned a function at [dansnetwork.com](http://dansnetwork.com/2008/11/01/javascript-iso8601rfc3339-date-parser/) that claims to be able to parse ISO8601 strings into `Date` objects. Or you could try parsing it yourself (Check out [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), and the [Date](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date) api.). Luckily for you, I believe I read [somewhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) that Mozilla's Javascript 1.8.5 is going to support ISO8601 strings in its native `parse()` function. Hopefully the rest will follow suit shortly.